Sodium zincate reaction
does adding zinc chloride into the solution of sodium zincate formed by the reaction of zinc chloride and excess of sodium hydroxide form the precipitate of zinc hydroxide ? I mean does sodium zincate react with zinc chloride to give the precipitate or both soluble compounds just remain in the solution ? I have no access to labs, I am just interested in this subject.

[Zn(H2O)6]^2+ + [Zn(OH)4(H2O)2]^2- -> 2 [Zn(OH)2(H2O)4], with the product condensation and coagulation.
